# Get a MYSQL Query from .php?id=

Tags: php, mysql

Let's just say for the purpose of this question, we have a blog. Now, on that default page for the blog displays the latest... 10 posts let's say.

These posts have been retrieved from a MySql query in PHP.

What I want to know is, how do you then, create a link on that latest blog posts page which takes you to the actual page of the blog post?

I'm guessing it's going to be something like:

```
http://www.example.com/showposts.php?id=1
```

But I don't know how to set that up to get the post query from the MySql database?

Please help me out,

Adam.

Comment: select whatever from table where primarykey=your_sanitized_id_from_get

Comment: Or ask an IT professional. Considering your question, you will have a hard time making the blog. My suggestion may seem harsh, but SO helps people having a particular problem - not to make a whole implementation. Ask a friend in IT - you'll get what you want, plus some valuable explanations.

Comment: I have everything coded already - I just had no idea how to do that with URL's. I learnt PHP in a weird order :P. Nevertheless, thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result =  mysql_query("select * from table where id = " . intval($_GET['id']));
```

An even cleaner way would be using prepared statements (via mysqli or PDO). However, that's outside the scope of the question and you'll already find tons of information about it here on SO.

Comment: Ahhhhh! The MySql prepared statements thing sounds cool, I'll look into that. But thanks that's helped me so much! Perfect!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just don't forget to escape the value as well:

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE tableID = ' . mysql_real_escape_string(trim(intval($_GET['id']))));
```

Just to be on the safe side.